# Set RadioButtonList First ListItem as Selected

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using jquery and c# to dynamically set a radiobuttonlist listitem to selected. I want to create a reset-type button to reset the radiobuttonlist selected item back to the first item in the list.

jQuery/jsTree function currently reseting textbox and hidden field:

```
$('#ContentPlaceHolder1_hfNodeID').val('');
$('.txtPage').val('');
$('.rblContentTypesGetAll').val();
$('.contentPageForm').show(),
```

`.rblContentTypesGetAll` is the radiobuttonlist i want to reset (or select the top most listitem).

HTML of the form:

```
 <asp:Panel ID="PagesForm" CssClass="contentPageForm" runat="server">
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hfNodeID" runat="server" Value="" />
 <table>
     <tr>
        <td>Page</td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtPage" CssClass="txtPage" runat="server" /><span class="validate">*</span><br />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPage" runat="server" CssClass="validate" ControlToValidate="txtPage" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Page Name Required" ValidationGroup="page" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content Type</td>
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButtonList id="rblContentTypesGetAll" CssClass="rblContentTypesGetAll" OnLoad="rblContentTypesGetAll_Load"  runat="server" >
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="PageSubmit_Click" Text="Save" ValidationGroup="page" />
             <asp:Button ID="Cancel" runat="server" OnClick="Cancel_Click" Text="Cancel" />
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
 </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Please post some HTML for us to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#rblContentTypesGetAll_0').attr('checked', 'checked');`

**EDIT**

Bry4n says the following worked for him:

```
$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_rblContentTypesGetAll_0").attr("checked", "checked");
```

Comment: @Bry4n I've never used asp so I'm not sure what HTML gets created. I edited the code.

Comment: @Kyle it removed the active radiobutton but didn't reselect the first item.

Comment: If I use the ID I would need to make it like that, I am using classes.

Comment: @Bry4n , do you have a live version I can see? It all depends on how asp generates the HTML.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a live version. I'll update the top with the generated HTML

Comment: Ah You were right the ID of the upper most input needed to be used. I had my mind wrapped around the radiobuttonlist as a whole. Good job Kyle

Comment: @Bry4n I'm going to edit the answer and remove everything but the jQuery line with the ID so anyone who visits this page will see the answer quickly. Is this the line that worked? `$('#rblContentTypesGetAll_0').attr('checked', 'checked');`

Comment: `$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_rblContentTypesGetAll_0").attr("checked", "checked");` Worked for me. I didn't even have to remove the other one

Answer (score 0):

Have you missed the parameter to `val`?

```
$('.rblContentTypesGetAll').val('');
```